# how to put a p element below the svg icon in a div element html css?

Tags: html, css, svg

I Have a div(a box) and inside this div, I have an SVG icon/img and I want a p or something(a text) under the icon/img on each icon/img. I want to know How can I do this?
My problem is why I don't have a p or something like a text (test) on each element?
I use HTML, CSS, bootstrap, and SVG icons.

My code :

```css
p,
td {
  color: white;
}

img {
  /* width: 35%; */
  /* text-align: center; */
  /* margin: 0 0 0 55px; */
  padding: 18px 19px 24px 20px;
}

img:hover {
  border: 3px solid #dee77a;
}

.icone {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 20px 0 15px 52px;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(249, 244, 244, .1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transition-property: color;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 4px 1px rgb(9 9 12 / 50%);
}

.skill-name {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 9em;
  bottom: 80px;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #aa6d12;
  z-index: auto;
}

.skill {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: raw;
  width: 66%;
  height: 280px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}

.skill-framework {
  margin-top: 300px;
}

.skill-language>.icone,
.skill-framework>.icone,
.skill-other>.icone {
  margin: auto;
  /* background: lime; */
  width: auto;
}

.box {
  background-color: var(--main-bg);
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="box">
  <h1>Skills</h1>
  
  <div class="table-responsive-lg table-skill">
    <div class="skill skill-language">
      <img class="icone" src="img/icone/html5-original.svg" />
      <p class="skill-name">test</p>

      <img class="icone" src="img/icone/css3-original.svg" />
      <p class="skill-name">test</p>

      <img class="icone" src="img/icone/javascript-original.svg" />
      <p class="skill-name">test</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="skill skill-framework">
      <img class="icone" src="img/icone/angularjs-original.svg" />
      <img class="icone" src="img/icone/react-original.svg" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="skill skill-other">
      <img class="icone" src="img/icone/materialui-original.svg" />
      <img class="icone" src="img/icone/bootstrap-original.svg" />
      <img class="icone" src="img/icone/visualstudio-plain.svg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Because the position absolute of text corresponds to the parent div. So you positioned 3x p tag to the same place.

Comment: Create a wrapper for each img + p and than position the p.. and it will work as you wish :)

Comment: I have a new problem : my p element is not center and he is outside in the img. For example it's a long p like Material UI it is outside of the frame.

Comment: try to read more about positioning to center it. And read more about [sizing](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp) the element not to get it out of the frame. Its really basic knowledge.

Comment: thank you for your help ! i'm going to read your advice :) 
I try to build a portfolio and I have so many idea for build this. 
Do you know if it's bad to watch other website and to watch the code for learn and inspire me ?

Comment: If you are total begginer, you can go threw https://www.w3schools.com/ or sololearn? I dont know a lot of websites. Some youtube tutorials are usefull. But maybe its better to find some course, f.e. from Bootcamp teachers (not necessary the Bootcamp itself, I saw some video tutorials with teachers from Bootcamp on Udemy and elswhere, it doesnt cost a lot). The whole course gives you some order - what to learn. If you dont understand everything about topic, than you will search the topic, but still you will know what you need to learn next :)

Comment: sorry that I say it in confusing way. Its really morning in my country :)

Comment: I'm not a total beginner but I need a mentor. May u to be my mentor ?  
I'm not sure if it's allow to chat here, i'm new in stackoverflow. but not new in web dev.

Comment: There are public chats. Or we can meet on slack. Did you study and solve your positioning problem?

Comment: Yeah I solve the problem but it's not perfect pixel and responsively it's bad :/
I try to solve the problem for the responsive, I use media query.